# node.js request.get responsed with html body ignoring 404 status

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have troubles with node.js [***request***](https://github.com/request/request) module. I need to get html body of a page, so I make GET request to url in this way:

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = { 
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
};
var url = "http://shop.nag.ru/catalog/14019.Шкафы-телекоммуникационные/14020.Напольные-шкафы/14024.600x600/08061.SNR-TFC-376060-G";

request.get({url: url, headers: headers }, function (err, response, body) {
  console.log("stat" + response.statusCode);
   console.log("body" + body);

});
```

And it responds with an html body. But if you follow the same link in browser, you will see a page with `404 error`: [http://shop.nag.ru/catalog/14019.Шкафы-телекоммуникационные/14020.Напольные-шкафы/14024.600x600/08061.SNR-TFC-376060-G](http://shop.nag.ru/catalog/14019.%D0%A8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/14020.%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B/14024.600x600/08061.SNR-TFC-376060-G)
" (url use Russian alphabet).
So what is the problem? Why [***request***](https://github.com/request/request) didn't return response with *'404'* status?

Comment: What status does it return? When I use your exact code, `response.statusCode` is 404. What's the issue?

Comment: sorry I post wrong url, I changed url now, and you will see that status is 200 for request module and 404 from browser

Comment: if(response.statusCode == "404"){res.send("404 not found")}

Comment: I want to download html body of a page, and if url is not valid I want to receive '404', not '200' status as now,  from remote third-party server inside my callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) the url. Most browsers do it by default, so when you try to hit from the browser an url like:

> [http://shop.nag.ru/catalog/14019.Шкафы-телекоммуникационные/14020.Напольные-шкафы/14024.600x600/08061.SNR-TFC-376060-G](http://shop.nag.ru/catalog/14019.%D0%A8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/14020.%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B/14024.600x600/08061.SNR-TFC-376060-G)

You actually send a request to:

> http://shop.nag.ru/catalog/14019.%D0%A8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/14020.%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B/14024.600x600/08061.SNR-TFC-376060-G`

But if you run a request with the help of node `request` module, the url is not being encoded. So you should do it by yourself:

```
request.get({url: encodeURI(url), headers: headers }, function (err, response, body) { 
    // ... 
});
```